# Set axis range in databricks plot

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with dates and counts.  I want to create a plot in databricks of this which is easy enough.  However, the y-axis does not start at 0, rather the min seems to be picked automatically.  I think this is misleading on my dataset and would like to set the axis to 0.

However, there is no information in the docs or anything and the plot options are very limited.

Is there some option that I can trigger that allows this?  Thanks.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(_c0=1, _c1='169476969'),
 Row(_c0=2, _c1='172966662'),
 Row(_c0=3, _c1='166889786'),
 Row(_c0=4, _c1='127088937'),
 Row(_c0=5, _c1='118771203')]).toDF('Instance', 'Volume')
```

Plot Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that there are not any other options, only except `Plot Options` as the figure below can help to customize plot simply.

[image]

And according to the offical document, the only way to customize plot as you wish is to follow [HTML, D3, and SVG in Notebooks](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/visualizations/html-d3-and-svg.html) to customize plot by [`displayHTML` function](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/visualizations/index.html#displayhtml-function). If you have to show the original point in your plot, you can refer to a D3 sample [`Line Chart`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart) to draw it via `displayHTML`.

Hope it helps.